# Yogurt made with heavy cream

Tags: yogurt, cream, frozen-yogurt

I like to make yogurt from heavy cream so when it's frozen, it keeps creamy texture when stored in the freezer in several days. Do you think this works? Does high fat content affect incubation process of yogurt? Should I use heavy cream or half heavy cream half whole milk?

Comment: I answered, but misread the question.  Do you want to make the yogurt with cream...or add cream to yogurt when making frozen yogurt?  Also, your question probably won't survive long if you are just asking whether or not this is a good idea.  We don't really respond to opinion based questions. So, you might want to re-frame your question.

Comment: Thank you, I edited my question. I want to make yogurt with cream then freeze it after incubation

Comment: Should this say "I *would* like to make.."? Right now it reads like you currently enjoy making yogurt with cream, which makes the whole question confusing.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very normal thing to do. The result is not called yogurt, but sour cream. You can use yogurt, especially lactobacillus yogurt, as a starter for full-fat sour cream of the Eastern European type. The fermentation process is the same as for yogurt. It gets a very nice characteristic smell which is different from that of yogurt. It might stay slightly soupier than yogurt, even after sitting in the fridge, that's normal.

There is nothing special you need to consider, just go ahead and make it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add cream to milk when making yogurt.  This will increase the fat content.  However, if by "creamy", you are referring to texture of your yogurt, there are other variables that contribute besides fat content. See [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/84903/controlling-variables-in-homemade-yogurt), for example.  Also, there are variables besides fat (sugar content, for example) that influence the texture of frozen ices.